# Audit daemon does not take rules from audit.rules

Tags: yocto, audit

I am unable to add rules to audit daemon using  /etc/audit/audit.rules
Every time i add the rules using auditctl it gets removed on reboot or audit daemon restart I have attached the /etc/audit/audit.rules and /etc/audit/auditd.conf 
**cat /etc/audit/auditd.conf**

```
$ cat /etc/audit/auditd.conf 
#
# This file controls the configuration of the audit daemon
#

local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /NU_Application/audit.log
log_group = root
log_format = RAW
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 8
num_logs = 5
priority_boost = 4
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = ROTATE
space_left = 75
space_left_action = SYSLOG
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
##tcp_listen_port = 22
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
```

**cat /etc/audit/audit.rules**

```
$ cat /etc/audit/audit.rules 
## First rule - delete all

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
-b 8192

## This determine how long to wait in burst of events
--backlog_wait_time 0

## Set failure mode to syslog
-f 1
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa
root@iWave-G22M:~# auditctl
```

When i restart the audit daemon ( i.e /etc/init.d/auditd restart ) and try to list the rules i get the message No rules

```
$ /etc/init.d/auditd restart
Restarting audit daemon auditd
type=1305 audit(1558188111.980:3): audit_pid=0 old=1148 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
 res=1
type=1305 audit(1558188112.010:4): audit_enabled=1 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
 res=1
type=1305 audit(1558188112.020:5): audit_pid=30342 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
 res=1
1
$ auditctl -l               
No rules
```

OS INFO

```
$ uname -a
Linux iWave-G22M 3.10.31-ltsi-svn743 #5 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 27 18:28:01 IST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

audit_2.8.4.bb file was used to install auditd daemon via yocto
path of audit_2.8.4.bb -- http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/tree/recipes-security/audit/audit_2.8.4.bb?h=master

Answer (score 1):

audit rules add via **/etc/audit/audit.rules** and **auditctl** command are not permanent. to make them permanent across reboot you have to add them **/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules** file.
after adding the rule, restart **auditd service** and run command **auditctl -l**, it will list all the rules and also reflect in **/etc/audit/audit.rules** file.